# QGIS, .asc to .dwg error

Tags: qgis, translation

I am trying to convert an .asc file to .dwg using QGIS but I receive the following error:

> ERROR 1: CAD driver has no creation capabilities

Could anyone please advise what the problem could be?

I suspect it is a bug.

Comment: What makes you think it's a bug?  Could it just be that creation of DWG format is not supported?

Comment: I think user30184 has answered this part, it's a read-only. I suspected it's a bug because I could convert to an .xyz but not .dwg

Comment: @Liverpoolaki you have just faced one of the key disadvantages of close formats as the countless revisions of the .dwg. It is better to avoid them as much as possible. Long life to the [Open formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format)!

Comment: That would be ideal but when I have to send the information to the engineers then a .dwg or a .dxf file are my only options. I was expecting to see more improvements on Arcmap 10.5 but not a lot was improved to be honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QGIS is using this GDAL driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_cad.html.

The last row on the manual page says

> The driver is read-only.

So not a bug. Try to use DXF http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html as an interchange format.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to reply! Much appreciated! I'm not very confident with QGIS but I try to use it more often since it's solved so many of my problems before. Thanks again!